# How can I implement and use command prompt commands through the java and see results in java?

Tags: java, cmd

How can I implement and use command prompt commands through the java and see results in java? The command prompt commands are following:

1. `cd Desktop\nikto-2.1.4`
2. `nikto.pl -h www.cirt.net -ssl .`

What I should do in order to be able to use those commands in java and to see results?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would use ProcessBuilder to set the current directory and run the second command using `cmd.exe`. I would combine the error and output and read the output into your Java program.

Comment: thank you for your response but can you explain please in more details and if possible i need some source codes

Comment: Can you please elaborate ? I got stuck in the same problem. :(

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to run comands is by using *Process* object.

```
String[] commands = { "cd Desktop\nikto-2.1.4", "nikto.pl -h www.cirt.net -ssl ." }
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec( commands );
try {
    InputStream is = process.getInputStream();
    try {
        //.... do something        
    } 
    finally { is.close(); }
}
finally { process.destroy(); }
```

Now handling all of these different streams can be messy, thus -> java.lang.ProcessBuilder suggested by Mr. Lawrey. It is a utility class provided by JVM intended to simplify usage of Process object. It would make given example more tolerable.

Answer (score 0):

The following code will display the output of `nikto.pl -h www.cirt.net -sslb`, allowing you to capture and manipulate it.

```
cd Desktop\nikto-2.1.4
for /f "tokens=*" %%x in ('nikto.pl -h www.cirt.net -sslb') do echo %%x
```